# Javascript store inner object in map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, three.js

```
   this.meshMap = new Object();

    this.addMesh = function(key,url)
        {
          var map = this.meshMap; // redefinition

          var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

          loader.load( url, function(geometry)
          {
                map[key] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); // object to store

                scene.add(map[key]); // Works
          });

          map[key].position = new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, 0); // ERROR: Null

        }
```

How do i store the mesh in to the map correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure map[key] (your this.meshMap) is an object when calling addMesh. Note this is not the same as saying map itself is an object. If map[key] is not an object, it cannot have properties (such as position).

You can try the following:

```
this.meshMap = new Object();

this.addMesh = function(key,url)
    {
      var map = this.meshMap; // redefinition

      var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

      loader.load( url, function(geometry)
      {
            map[key] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); // object to store
            map[key].position = new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, 0); // ERROR: Null
            scene.add(map[key]); // Works
      });


    }
```

Comment: how would i do that exactly? I dont understand why im getting a null pointer.

Comment: if (map[key]) map[key].position = new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, 0);

Comment: ok i did that, the if statement did not run. meaning the object return is null?

Comment: You can also move your line into the block after setting map[key] to a new Mesh. Since this part is event driven, it will only happen AFTER giving it a value, whereas now it happens BEFORE.

Comment: yes i can do that. but what i need it to have access to the mesh after its created.

Comment: That's exactly what you'll have. I edited my answer to reflect my suggestion.

Comment: this works but this.meshMap still has 0 elements inside?

Comment: I suspect that would depend on when you count its elements. Try counting them right after setting map[key]. You would probably have one element. Again, I think your issue is not taking into account that event driven functions are called later and "outside" of your code flow.